# What would be a suitable textbook of ordinary differential equations for such content?

Tags: textbook-recommendation

I'm a first year undergraduate in Math. And I'm going to take the course "Analysis II" in the next semester.

Half of the course will be spent on ODEs, but from the content of the lecture notes I couldn't find any suitable English textbook available.

The content goes as follows

6.1. Solutions by Integration

6.2. The Existence and Uniqueness Theorem

6.3. Systems of Differential Equations

6.4. Differential Equations of Higher Orders

6.5. Applications of the Uniqueness Theorem

6.6. Linear Differential Equations with constant coefficients

6.7. Complex Numbers

6.8. Back to Linear Differential Equations

I notice that we will reach the existence and uniqueness theorem very fast, which is usually one of the last chapters in most ODE textbooks (e.g. Boyce, Edwards, etc.)

I appreciate it if you can recommend me some more references. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The first five chapters of the text book *Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems*, by Gerald Teschl, seem to proceed along the same lines as your course. The book is [published](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-140) by the AMS, but a legitimate free version can be downloaded from the author's [web site.](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf)